# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'transformFile') mac

Tags: react-native

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'transformFile')
at Bundler.transformFile (/Users/.../node_modules/metro/src/Bundler.js:48:30)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async Object.transform (/Users/.../node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:101:12)
at async processModule (/Users/victorgelvis/Documents/mts/mts-app/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:137:18)
at async traverseDependenciesForSingleFile (/Users/victorgelvis/Documents/mts/mts-app/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:131:3)
at async Promise.all (index 0)
at async initialTraverseDependencies (/Users/victorgelvis/Documents/mts/mts-app/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:114:3)
at async DeltaCalculator._getChangedDependencies (/Users/victorgelvis/Documents/mts/mts-app/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/DeltaCalculator.js:164:25)
at async DeltaCalculator.getDelta (/Users/victorgelvis/Documents/mts/mts-app/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/DeltaCalculator.js:94:16)
at async DeltaBundler.buildGraph (/Users/victorgelvis/Documents/mts/mts-app/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler.js:50:5)

```
npx react-native info
```

info Fetching system and libraries information...
System:
OS: macOS 13.3.1
CPU: (8) arm64 Apple M1
Memory: 106.48 MB / 8.00 GB
Shell: 5.9 - /bin/zsh
Binaries:
Node: 16.20.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.0/bin/node
Yarn: 1.22.19 - /opt/homebrew/bin/yarn
npm: 8.19.4 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.0/bin/npm
Watchman: Not Found
Managers:
CocoaPods: 1.12.1 - /opt/homebrew/bin/pod
SDKs:
iOS SDK:
Platforms: DriverKit 22.2, iOS 16.2, macOS 13.1, tvOS 16.1, watchOS 9.1
Android SDK: Not Found
IDEs:
Android Studio: Not Found
Xcode: 14.2/14C18 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
Languages:
Java: Not Found
npmPackages:
@react-native-community/cli: Not Found
react: 17.0.2 => 17.0.2
react-native: 0.67.2 => 0.67.2
react-native-macos: Not Found
npmGlobalPackages:
*react-native*: Not Found

init my project of react native